# How to implement cache with ActiveRecord and Pagination in Yii Framework 2?

Tags: php, caching, pagination, yii2

I would like implement cache for the results of `ActiveRecord` with pagination implemented. But the pagination button does not query next records. It keeps showing the same first 15 records even I click on another page number. Assume 15 is the `pageSize`.

This is how my code in the controller looks like.

```
$query = Article::find()->where(['status' => 1]);

// get the total number of articles (but do not fetch the article data yet)
$count = $query->count();

// create a pagination object with the total count
$pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $count, 'pageSize' => 15]);

// limit the query using the pagination and retrieve the articles
$query = $query->offset($pagination->offset)->limit($pagination->limit);

$userId = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;

$articles =  Yii::$app->cache->getOrSet($userId, function () use($query) {
    return $query->all();
});

return $this->render('inbox', [
    'articles' => $articles,
    'pagination' => $pagination,
]);
```

Below is my `view`.

```
foreach($articles as $article) {
     //...
}

<?= LinkPager::widget(['pagination' => $pagination, ]) ?>
```

How to implement `cache` with `ActiveRecord` and `Pagination` in Yii framework 2?